# SQL select 6 rows ordering by time

Tags: mysql, select

I was thinking how to make SQL that should grab info I want. And I could'nt find the answer. I need to make SQL, which grabs 6 most downloaded records within 48 hours from my table and order it by time. My table looks like

this is how my table looks like: http://puu.sh/4VL9z.png

so the query should grab unique rows (by IP, there shouldn't be same downloader_ip) within 48 hours and then grab only 6 popular rows ordering by downloads and display it by "modification_id". There should be 6 different "modification_id".

So how to make SQL like that?

**EDIT**

i will imagine if i have the rows:

```
| id | modification_id | time | file_name | downloader_ip |

| 1 | 320 | 1382368921 | name.rar | 127.01.015.14|

| 2 | 322 | 1382368925 | name.rar | 127.02.015.14 |

| 3 | 325 | 1382368926 | name.rar | 127.03.015.14 |

| 4 | 326 | 1382368928 | name.rar | 127.04.015.14 |

| 5 | 328 | 1382368930 | name.rar | 127.05.015.14 |

| 6 | 330 | 1382368935 | name.rar | 127.06.015.14 |
```

so if the table would look like this, so the query should display rows 1-6 (by id).

Comment: If you share what you attempted till now (the sql you wrote, even if wrong) you will get more answers

Comment: the problem is, that I can't even imagine how the SQL should look like

Comment: More sample data would be good.

Comment: ok, I will add some picture

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, you can't use a `DISTINCT` because that's a post-filter. You'll have to use `GROUP BY` instead, which gives you unique on a column (or group of columns). Combine that with a `DATE_SUB` (to restrict based on date), and a `LIMIT` (to restrict down to 6 entries), and you should be good!

```
SELECT *
FROM download_records
WHERE
    time >= DATE_SUB(time,INTERVAL 2 DAY)
GROUP BY modification_id
ORDER BY time DESC
LIMIT 0, 6
```

Comment: that returns me error

Comment: `Error Number: 1064

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'GROUP BY `modification_id` LIMIT 0, 6' at line 1

SELECT * FROM `mods_downloads` WHERE `time` >= DATE_SUB(time,INTERVAL 2 DAY) ORDER BY time DESC GROUP BY `modification_id` LIMIT 0, 6`

Comment: My mistake, `GROUP BY` needs to come before `ORDER BY`. You may need to tweak the time WHERE `clause` as well; I tested it on a DATETIME field rather than a Unix timestamp.

Comment: how it should look like on timestamp? i can't get it